# Very high gas for simple function call only on mainnet

Tags: solidity, ether, metamask, gas, etherscan

This is a quite simple contract. Everything works fine, both locally and on rinkeby testnet. Average gas cost for enrol function is around 250,000 gas units. On mainnet it spikes a lot without an apparent reason. Tried with both with and without optimizer on version 0.8.10+

[image]

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol";

contract MetaCityAlphaClub is Ownable {
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;

    struct Alpha {
        bool isAvailable;
        uint256 availableSlots;
        uint256 daysAvailable;
        uint256 creationDate;
        uint256 price;
        uint256 id;

        EnumerableSet.AddressSet registeredAddresses;
    }

    modifier authorised() {
        require(authorisedAddresses[msg.sender], "The token contract is not authorised");
        _;
    }

    address public tokenAddress;
    address public nftAddress;

    uint256 constant private ETHER = 10 ** 18;
    uint256 constant private DAYS = 24 * 60 * 60;

    mapping(uint256 => Alpha) private alphaConfig;
    mapping(address => bool) public authorisedAddresses;

    uint256[] public alphaList;

    constructor(
        address tokenAddress_,
        address nftAddress_
    ) {
        tokenAddress = tokenAddress_;
        nftAddress = nftAddress_;
    }

    function setAuthorisedStatuses(address[] calldata addresses_, bool[] calldata statuses_) external onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < addresses_.length; ++i) {
            authorisedAddresses[addresses_[i]] = statuses_[i];
        }
    }

    function setTokenAddress(address tokenAddress_) external onlyOwner {
        tokenAddress = tokenAddress_;
    }

    function setnftAddress(address humansAddress_) external onlyOwner {
        nftAddress = nftAddress_;
    }

    function addAlpha(
        uint256 availbleSlots_,
        uint256 availbleDays_,
        uint256 price_,
        uint256 id_
    ) external authorised {
        Alpha storage alpha_ = alphaConfig[id_];
        require(alpha_.creationDate == uint256(0), "Project already exists");
        alpha_.isAvailable = true;
        alpha_.availableSlots = availbleSlots_;
        alpha_.daysAvailable = availbleDays_;
        alpha_.creationDate = block.timestamp;
        alpha_.price = price_;
        alphaList.push(id_);
    }

    function setAlphaStatus(uint256 id_, bool status_) authorised external {
        Alpha storage alpha_ = alphaConfig[id_];
        require(alpha_.creationDate != uint256(0), "Project does not exists");

        alpha_.isAvailable = status_;
    }

    function setAlphaAvailableSlots(uint256 id_, uint256 availableSlots_) authorised external {
        Alpha storage alpha_ = alphaConfig[id_];
        require(alpha_.creationDate != uint256(0), "Project does not exists");

        alpha_.availableSlots = availableSlots_;
    }

    function setAlphaAvailableDays(uint256 id_, uint256 daysAvailable_) authorised external {
        Alpha storage alpha_ = alphaConfig[id_];
        require(alpha_.creationDate != uint256(0), "Project does not exists");

        alpha_.daysAvailable = daysAvailable_;
    }

    function setAlphaPrice(uint256 id_, uint256 price_) authorised external {
        Alpha storage alpha_ = alphaConfig[id_];
        require(alpha_.creationDate != uint256(0), "Project does not exists");

        alpha_.price = price_;
    }

    function getRegisteredAddresses(uint256 id_) external view returns(address[] memory) {
        address[] memory addresses = new address[](alphaConfig[id_].registeredAddresses.length());

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < alphaConfig[id_].registeredAddresses.length(); ++i) {
            addresses[i] = alphaConfig[id_].registeredAddresses.at(i);
        }

        return addresses;
    }

    function getAlphaConfig(uint256 id_) external view returns(bool, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        Alpha storage alpha_ = alphaConfig[id_];
        require(alpha_.creationDate != uint256(0), "Project already exists");

        return (alpha_.isAvailable, alpha_.availableSlots, alpha_.daysAvailable, alpha_.creationDate, alpha_.price);
    }

    function enroll(uint256 id_) external {
        Alpha storage alpha_ = alphaConfig[id_];

        require(alpha_.isAvailable, "Project is not available");
        if (alpha_.daysAvailable != uint256(0)) {
            require(alpha_.creationDate + alpha_.daysAvailable * DAYS >= block.timestamp, "End date reached");
        }
        if (alpha_.availableSlots != uint256(0)) {
            require(alpha_.registeredAddresses.length() < alphaConfig[id_].availableSlots, "Available slots filled");
        }
        require(IERC721(nftAddress).balanceOf(_msgSender()) > 0, "You do not own humans");

        alphaConfig[id_].registeredAddresses.add(msg.sender);

        if (alpha_.price != uint256(0)) {
            IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(_msgSender(), tokenAddress, alpha_.price * ETHER);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The gas show by metamask is above 24M. My guess is that you have a bug in the function enroll or something wasn't initialized properly in mainnet.

Comment: @Ismael configurations are done via hardhat scripts, not manually. On testnet works and consumes reasonable gas units.

Comment: Did you deploy in a public testnet like ropsten, rinkeby, etc? If you deployed the same contract in testnet and mainnet and it just fails in mainnet then the code is fine, the error must be in the contract state at the time of the call. Did you try forcing gas to 250,000?

Comment: @Ismael it has been deployed on rinkeby and it works just fine. Tried hardcoding the gas but once the transaction is submitted it runs out of gas

Comment: Do you have the failed transaction hash? You could debug it using tenderly dashboard.